# Embed A Remote Desktop

Tags: iframe, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

Im trying to make a website simular to hackthebox where you get your own virtual matchine in a iframe. However, I cannot seem to find a servive or explanation of how to do this.

I have all the servers avalable just need the software.

Hopefully someone out there knows how to do this or has a simular issue.

Thanks

Currently I have tried anydesk, but this is too complicated for people who want to just try and hack without having to open a seprate app or tab.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [OS.js](https://www.os-js.org/?)? Which is an open-source JavaScript web desktop platform with a window manager, application APIs, GUI toolkit, filesystem abstractions and much more.

Comment: Was this helpful?